# C Comment in Emacs - Linux Kernel Style

Tags: emacs, comments, elisp

I'm using

```
(setq-default comment-style 'multi-line)
```

and my region comments, when doing <kbd>M-;</kbd>, are:

```
/* void main()
 * {
 *  int i;
 *  int b;
 *  printf("format string");
 * } */
```

But I want them to look like this:

```
/* 
 * void main()
 * {
 *  int i;
 *  int b;
 *  printf("format string");
 * }
 */
```

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
(setq comment-style 'extra-line)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks. Emacs really rocks.

Comment: I noticed that last line of the comment has spaces and not tabs. How could we cincumvent that to use only tabs for comment alignment?

Answer (score 0):

**Complementing the anler answer and answering my own question.**

To use the Linux Kernel commenting Style [1] in emacs, just set this variable in your *.emacs/init.el*:

```
(setq comment-style 'extra-line)
```

To comment/uncomment use **<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>** after select the region.

*To fix needless comment spaces when using tabs see [C Comment in Emacs - Linux Kernel Style v2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34780473/2776344).*

[1] https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle