# C Comment in Emacs - Linux Kernel Style v2

Tags: emacs, elisp

I received an answer about [C Comment in Emacs - Linux Kernel Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172561/c-comment-in-emacs-linux-kernel-style) that works great but

[image]

when emacs comments (`comment-dwim`) it's padding the second `* long_function_name_vari` and last `*/` lines with spaces (before the comment) not tabs like I have configured it. How to avoid that?

And how easily to make a comment using this style?

```
    /* void main()
     * {
     *  int i;
     *  int b;
     *  printf("format string");
     * }
     */
```

Comment: Not related to the other tags, just about emacs.

Comment: This issue was patched on [emacs-25](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/016b3d5894b8c424eab262aeefc646c6cd03a70a) git branch :-D But

Answer (score 2):

Customizable variable `comment-style` is defined in newcomment.el saying
...

```
(extra-line t   nil t   t
            "One comment for all lines, end on a line by itself")
```

...

which should deliver the wanted result IIUC.

Current implementation however is two-extra-lines, the opening newline undocumented so far. Please file a feature request resp. docu-bug report.

Comment: Thank you. I just sent a bug report. I think that extra-line could be splitted in three news styles (extra-line-top, extra-line-bottom, extra-lines).

Answer (score 0):

Well, after seek the `newcomment.el` I could understand how to tweak that behavior.

```
(defun my-c-comment-dwim (tabify delete-trailing)      
  (interactive)
  (let (beg end)
    (if (region-active-p)
        (progn
          (setq beg (region-beginning)
                end (region-end))
          (if (comment-only-p beg end)
              (uncomment-region beg end)
            (progn
              (comment-region beg end)
              (when (equal comment-style 'extra-line)
                (save-excursion
                  (goto-char end)
                  (forward-line 2)
                  (setq end (line-end-position))))
              (when tabify
                (tabify beg end))
              (when delete-trailing
                (delete-trailing-whitespace beg end)))))
      (comment-indent))))

(global-set-key [remap comment-dwim] (lambda ()
                                       (interactive)
                                       (my-c-comment-dwim t t)))
```

Comment: Congratulation. Assume use of forward-line is preferable here over next-line.